# Which identification field to use as primary key in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

For security reasons, I am using MD5-encoded random strings  (by `PHP`) as handles in a database so HTML form fields aren't so easily compromised (`auto_increment` hidden input values or URLs could simply be incremented manually). Tables also have an id field which I use purely for table joins, so the table looks a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `handle` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
 UNIQUE KEY `handle` (`handle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

1. Is this a suitable solution?
2. Keeping in mind the *handle* field's client-secure function and the *id* field's internal database function, which of these is best suited to be the primary index and which should be a unique (index)?

Answer (score 0):

From MySql manual:

> The primary key for a table represents the column or set of columns that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index, for fast query performance. Query performance benefits from the NOT NULL optimization, because it cannot include any NULL values. With the InnoDB storage engine, the table data is physically organized to do ultra-fast lookups and sorts based on the primary key column or columns.
>
> If your table is big and important, but does not have an obvious column or set of columns to use as a primary key, you might create a separate column with auto-increment values to use as the primary key. These unique IDs can serve as pointers to corresponding rows in other tables when you join tables using foreign keys.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html

From what you say the natural candidate to be a primary in your table is the id that will be used for internal joins. Your declaration makes correctly other keys.